# Magento2, how to display and get the custom table columns of sales_order table in rest API orders detail?

Tags: php, mysql, api, magento2

I have fetched the order details thorugh rest api in magento2. Here is the below code:

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "1");

$userData = array("username" => "ADMIN_USERNAME", "password" => "ADMIN_PASSWORD");
$ch = curl_init("https://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

echo $token = curl_exec($ch);

$ch = curl_init("https://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria=all");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

//var_dump($result);

$result = json_decode($result, 1);
echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
?>
```

**The output is in an array format. The default details are received but I have manually created 4 new columns from PHPMyAdmin (awb_no, prdt_type, prdt_code, client_code) in the sales_order table they are not present in the list see the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/tda4fb. I have no idea how to call them in API.**

I want the data of these 4 new columns in the rest API. Please help...

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

Please, when using a framework as strong as magento, don't just go to phpMyAdmin panel and add some columns somewhere. There is an official documentation on how to add custom information to orders, customers and products.
Add following code to `Vendor\Module\Setup\InstallSchema.php`:

```
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $connection = $installer->getConnection();

        if ($connection->tableColumnExists('sales_order', 'my_new_column') === false) {
            // get the table
            $table = $setup->getTable('sales_order');
            $connection->addColumn(
                $table,
                // column name
                'my_new_column',
                [
                    // The type of data, see Table class constants for more possibilities
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    // data length (max), 0 means no limit
                    'length' => 0,
                    // description
                    'comment' => 'My New Order Column'
                ]
            );
            $connection->addColumn(
                $table,
                'my_new_column_2',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 0,
                    'comment' => 'My New Order Column'
                ]
            );
        }
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

To access the new columns use:

```
$order->setMyNewColumn($value);
$value = $order->getMyNewColumn();
```

InstallSchema executes when you run `setup:upgrade` command and the Module was not already installed.

Now the last thing you need to do is overriding the API order action. Edit the `di.xml` to set a "preference" for the action class (this is the intended way to override Magento core code):

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface"
        type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Sales\Model\OrderRepository" />
</config>
```

And create the class that overrides the action in `app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Sales/Model/OrderRepository.php` directory:

```
<?php

namespace Magento\Sales\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria\CollectionProcessorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderSearchResultInterfaceFactory as SearchResultFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShippingAssignmentBuilder;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Metadata;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;


class OrderRepository extends \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository
{
    /**
     * @var OrderExtensionFactory
     */
    private $orderExtensionFactory;

    /**
     * @var ShippingAssignmentBuilder
     */
    private $shippingAssignmentBuilder;

    /**
     * @var CollectionProcessorInterface
     */
    private $collectionProcessor;

    /**
     * Find entities by criteria
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderSearchResultInterface
     */
    public function getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderSearchResultInterface         $searchResult */
        $searchResult = $this->searchResultFactory->create();
        $this->collectionProcessor->process($searchCriteria, $searchResult);
        $searchResult->setSearchCriteria($searchCriteria);
        foreach ($searchResult->getItems() as $order) {
            $this->setShippingAssignments($order);
            // whatever custom code you want to edit the response data with
            $myColumn = $order->getMyColumn();
        }
        return $searchResult;
    }

    /**
     * Private methods have to be redeclared as they are not
     * inherited
     *
     * @param OrderInterface $order
     * @return void
     */
    private function setShippingAssignments(OrderInterface $order)
    {
        /** @var OrderExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes */
        $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();

        if ($extensionAttributes === null) {
            $extensionAttributes = $this->orderExtensionFactory->create();
        } elseif ($extensionAttributes->getShippingAssignments() !== null) {
            return;
        }
        /** @var ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment */
        $shippingAssignments = $this->getShippingAssignmentBuilderDependency();
        $shippingAssignments->setOrderId($order->getEntityId());
        $extensionAttributes->setShippingAssignments($shippingAssignments->create());
        $order->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
    }

    /**
     * Private methods have to be redeclared as they are not
     * inherited
     *
     * @return ShippingAssignmentBuilder
     * @deprecated 100.0.4
     */
    private function getShippingAssignmentBuilderDependency()
    {
    if (!$this->shippingAssignmentBuilder instanceof ShippingAssignmentBuilder) {
        $this->shippingAssignmentBuilder = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
            \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShippingAssignmentBuilder::class
        );
        }
        return $this->shippingAssignmentBuilder;
    }
}
```

Now, you will need to add logic which populates your columns through your order creation. But adding all of the code for that would be way too much work for just an answer and my time is limited. I hope I could be of some help and maybe someone takes the time to edit my answer to contain all neccessary information.

Comment: In which file I have to use this code please tell, $order->setMyNewColumn($value);
$value = $order->getMyNewColumn();

Comment: See https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/ on how to create a new Extension/ Module in Magento 2. Inside of that Module, the InstallSchema.php file needs to be in a `Setup/` subdirectory.
You should probably remove the new columns via phpMyAdmin again, so that Magento can setup them up properly.

Comment: Then, you can access the columns value for each Order Object anywhere in your custom code by the code above. Note that the method you use has to be named after the column name, so for you it should be $order->getAwbNo().

Comment: You will have to override the API's Controller. I will add this to my answer.